# Extract uncompressed size of zip file embedded in jar

Tags: java, jar, zip

I have a zip file embedded in my jar and want to read the uncompressed size. My current way of doing this:

```java
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("files.zip").toURI()));
Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> e = zipFile.entries();
long installedSize = 0;
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
    ZipEntry entry = e.nextElement();
    installedSize += entry.getSize();
}
```

This is of course rather dirty and also doesn't work when I embed my jar file into an exe file using JSmooth.

Is there a better way of doing this (without copying the zip file)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getSize()` returns *uncompressed* size. This is in opposite to `getCompressedSize()`. And both work fine with zips either they are stored as stand alone file or embedded into other zip. 
Unfortunately I do not know how can you solve this with JSmooth.

If `files.zip` is your files you can check the entries size at build time and put the result into properties file. It is a patch, but it will work.